# Can one affine point on an elliptic curve have two Jacobians coordinates?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have theses output on curve for jacobian coordinates which I made doubling for `(3,10,1)` to get `(17,21,20)` then I made addition for all points to get this results:

```
     1     3    10     1
     2    17    21    20
     3    11    13     7
     4    20    21    14
     5     2     6     6
     6     9     1     8
     7    14    18     8
     8     6    13     2
     9     0    20    11
    10     3    18     9
    11     3    22     2
    12    10    17     5
    13     9    18    20
    14     3     0     8
    15    13     6     6
    16    10     6     5
    17     1    11    20
    18     3     5     9
    19     0    15     2
    20    13    16    22
    21    19    10    13
    22     8    20     4
    23     9     7     1
    24    14    19     6
    25    22    15    11
    26     5     4    21
    27    13    22    14
```

but when use scalar multiplication `double-and-add` Algorithm to get `4P` from `2P` then I got this coordinates `(10,9,12)` instead of `(20,21,14)`? I believe that two points are on the curve as `4P` because I revert them to affine and I got it correct affine coordinates for both are the same which is `(17,3)`

My question does One affine curve point has two jacobians?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, much like $\displaystyle\frac32$ and $\displaystyle\frac64$ are two different representations of the same rational number, a point on an Elliptic Curve has multiple different Jacobian representations.

$(X_0,Y_0,Z_0)$ and $(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)$ with $Z_0\ne0$ and $Z_1\ne0$ represent the same point in Jacobian coordinates if and only if ${Z_0}^2\,X_1={Z_1}^2\,X_0$ and ${Z_0}^3\,Y_1={Z_1}^3\,Y_0$, evaluated in the base field.

That can be rewritten $\displaystyle\frac{X_0}{{Z_0}^2}=\frac{X_1}{{Z_1}^2}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{Y_0}{{Z_0}^3}=\frac{Y_1}{{Z_1}^3}$, where the division is in the base field. The two quantities (on left and right of the previous *and*) are the Cartesian (aka affine) coordinates.

Curve point (other than the Elliptic Curve's neutral point/point at infinity) with Jacobian coordinates $(x,y,1)$ is the point with Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$.